# Mysql - Fetch row from join table based on the value from main table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in a MySQL database like this:

## Service:

```
service_id |userid      | service_name | pending  | accepted|completed 
-----------+------------+--------------+----------+---------+--------
1          | 1          |  Spa         | 1        |0        |0
2          | 2          |  Cleaning    | 0        |1        |0
3          | 3          |  General     | 1        |0        |0
```

## request_status: (id is primary key)

```
id  |  service_id   | Userid |  status      | accepted_date 
----+---------------+--------+--------------+---------------
1   |  1            |  1     |  Pending     | 2018/03/02
2   |  2            |  2     |  Pending     | 2018/03/02
3   |  2            |  2     |  Accepted    | 2018/03/05
4   |  3            |  3     |  Pending     | 2018/03/06
```

## OUTPUT

```
service_id   | service_name | userid|  Status    | Date
-----------+----------------+-------+------------+------------+---------
1          | Spa            | 1     |  Pending   | 2018/03/02
2          | Cleaning       | 2     |  Accepted  | 2018/03/05
3          | General        | 3     |  Pending   | 2018/03/06
```

For each Service user opt, the status will be update in another table request status.

I want the output with joining 2 tables with for each service its status. Eg. For the service id 2, its been accepted, so it has 2 entries in the second table. 
I tried with join but its fetching both pending and accepted for the service 2 which should fetch only one.

`SELECT a.*, b.* FROM service a left outer join request_statusb on a.service_id =b.service_id`

How to do that.? any help Please

Comment: You're looking for a `JOIN`. Have you [**tried anything so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in that regard?

Comment: You should atleast try something out or post what you have come up with.

Comment: get the id in request status table with max date group by service id and userid. then join to service table to get service name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM service a 
INNER JOIN request_status b ON a.service_id = b.service_id 
WHERE b.id = (SELECT max(id) FROM request_status rs WHERE rs.service_id = a.service_id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its perfect